# Remove space in horizontal menu that uses divs

Tags: html, css, spaces

I am trying to create a basic horizontal menu (no dropdown).  The images have been created for the menu, but I still see a space on the right hand side of the menu.  I created the navigation using divs. Most of the similar questions on Stack were for menus created with UL and LI, unlike mine.

My menu looks fine in IE, but not in FF, Chrome, Safari and Opera. ([Sample link](http://www.westmorelandfcu.org/studentbranch/test.aspx)) Can anyone explain why this is, and how I can fix it?

```
  <div style="width: 915px; height:33px;">
     <div  style="width:40px; height:33px; float:left;"><img runat="server" border="0" src="~/_images/_nav/nav_left.jpg" /></div>
    <div style="width:835px; height:33px; float: left; ">
    <div class="mynav" style="width:136px; height:33px; background-image:url(../_images/_nav/nav_student_left2.jpg)" ></div>
    <div class="mynav" style="width:155px; height:33px; background-image:url(../_images/_nav/nav_home2.jpg)"></div>
    <a runat="server" href="~/studentbranch/checking_savings/"><div class="mynav" style="width:134px; height:33px; background-image:url(../_images/_nav/nav_stash_my_cash2.jpg);" ></div></a>
    <a runat="server" href="~/studentbranch/loans/"><div class="mynav" style="width:133px; height:33px; background-image:url(../_images/_nav/nav_extra_credit2.jpg)"></div></a>
    <a runat="server" href="http://www.chachingteenclub.com/default.aspx?cu_id=92" target="_blank"><div class="mynav" style="width:134px; height:33px; background-image:url(../_images/_nav/nav_cha_ching2.jpg)"></div></a>
    <a runat="server" href="~/apps_tools/" target="_blank"><div class="mynav" style="width:135px; height:33px; background-image:url(../_images/_nav/nav_tools2.jpg)"></div></a>
    <div class="mynav" style="width:7px; height:33px; background-image:url(../_images/_nav/nav_student_right2.jpg);"></div>
    </div>
    <div style="width:40px; height: 33px; float:left;">
        <img runat="server" border="0" src="~/_images/_nav/nav_right.jpg" />
    </div>
    </div>
```

And the CSS

```
.mynav{
float:left;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
padding:0;
display:block;
border:0 none;
outline:0 none;
 }
```

Note: I have also tried using `display:inline` with no result.

Comment: I changed my answer, it would be a good idea to post an image of what the ideal situation looks like. At first I thought the image to the right of the colored images was the problem you were talking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit**: I removed my previous answer, this is more likely to be the problem (I don't have IE so I don't know what it is supposed to look like. Putting an image of the ideal case would be a good idea).

The containing `<div>` has a width of 835. Its children have widths: 136, 155, 134, 133, 134, 135, 7. In total that is 834 (which is one pixel less than 835). The vertical line to the right is the background color coming through.

**Edit (again)**: I remember IE having different floating behavior than the other browsers (or at least seeming to). Something you could try is just giving the menu containing `<div>` the appropriate `background-color` instead of playing with `<div>` widths.

Comment: Yes I needed both a left and right blank spacer for the nav bar since this was how my employer wanted it displayed on the mockup.  Any idea what 'exactly' is causing the vertical line space to the right nav_student_right2.jpg?

Comment: 834 is one less pixel than 835, I'm guessing that is what the vertical line is to the right

Comment: asimes - Thank you for your response.  I will take a look at the widths.  I tried to upload a screen shot, but because I'm a new member Stackoverflow doesn't allow it at this time :-\

Comment: You can use something like: http://imgur.com and then copy / paste the url to your image (after uploading the image there). Also, there is an easier solution than playing with the widths, I added it above.

Comment: Thanks again, asimes.  I tried the background color first but a space still showed up.  I then removed the image for the left hand div spacer and instead just made the background the same as the surrounding area.  I also increased it's width by 1px and that did the trick.  Can't thank you enough I've been trying to figure this out for the past 2 days.  :-)